# Materialize CSS - Carousel dentro de Collapsible

Tags: javascript, html5, materialize

Usando **Materialize CSS v1.0.0** (sin usar JQuery), al insertar un componente **Carousel** dentro de un **Collapsible** no se obtiene el comportamiento esperado (no se ve la tira de imágenes y se daña el efecto slide).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialdesignicons.css"/>
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href=""><img src="images/varelajp2.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href=""><img src="images/varelajp3.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href=""><img src="images/varelajp4.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Carousel on it</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
        <div class="carousel" id="carouselSports">
          <a class="carousel-item" href=""><img src="images/varelajp2.jpg"></a>
          <a class="carousel-item" href=""><img src="images/varelajp3.jpg"></a>
          <a class="carousel-item" href=""><img src="images/varelajp4.jpg"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script> <!--No se inserta JQuery.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript">M.AutoInit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Algunas soluciones sugieren inicializar el Carousel en el callback OnOpen (actuamente OnOpenStart) del plugin collapsible. Algo como:

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible({  
  onOpen: function() {  
    $('.carousel').carousel();  
  }  
})
```

La solución anterior es para versiones de Materialize CSS usando JQuery.
Se me ocurre imitarla inicializando según indica la nueva versión (con Javascript puro):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var collapsibles         = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
  var instanceCollapsibles = M.Collapsible.init(collapsibles,  {
    onOpenStart: function() {
      var carousels         = M.Carousel.getInstance(document.getElementById('carouselSports'));
      var instanceCarousels = M.Carousel.init(carousels, {
        indicators: true
      });
    }
  });
});
```

El evento OpenStart del Collapsible es bien capturado (probado con *console.log*), pero el Carousel sigue sin comportamiento correcto.
¿Alguna pista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estabas bien solo que el callback es **onOpenEnd**, así:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var collapsible = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
  var options = {
    onOpenEnd: function(){
      var carousel = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
      var cInstances = M.Carousel.init(carousel,{
        indicators: true
      });
      
    }
  };
  var instances = M.Collapsible.init(collapsible, options);
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Carousel</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <div class="carousel">
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
        
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```